# Return False with Alert upon webflow form submission

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a JS function which blocks users from submitting a personal email. Here is the code. When I remove the "alert" line, the user is blocked from a successful form submission. But there is no alert that prompts them to enter a business email.

```
$("form").submit(function(){

// Get the email value from the input with an id="Email-2"
var email_addr = $('#Email-2').val();

// The regex to check it against
var re = '[a-zA-Z_\\.-]+@((hotmail)|(yahoo)|(gmail))\\.[a-z]{2,4}';

// Check if the email matches
if(email_addr.match(re)){
    // Email is on the filter list
    // Return false and don't submit the form, or do whatever
    window.alert("Enter Business Email");
    return false;
} else {
    // Email ok
    // Allow the form to be submitted
    return true;
}});
```

Below is where there error is occuring. I'm new to Javascript so it very likely could be a syntax issue.

```
window.alert("Enter Business Email");
return false;
```

Comment: The comment says to look for an input with `id="email"` but your jQuery selector has `Email-2`. Which one is correct. Other than that your code seems to work

Comment: Email-2 is correct, just changed the comment

Comment: So joe.blogs1979@hotmail.com isn't a personal email but joe.blogs@hotmail.com is? (Note also that I've seen plenty of businesses (such as my plumber) use hotmail for professional purposes, and there are plenty of free email providers not on that list).

Comment: @Quentin just testing with those emails, going to add to it once I get the code working. We sell B2B, and any qualified customer (IE a software company with over 50 employees) we sell to would have a business email address

Comment: It appears to be an issue with the Regex, for example, say the email entered is xyz@gmail.com when I add 

console.log(email_addr)
console.log(email_addr.match(re))

it returns:

xyz@gmail.com
null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that worked, changed the code to the following:

```
$('#wf-form-Book-Demo-Form').submit(function(){ 
var email = $('#Email-2').val();
var reg = /^([\w-\.]+@(?!gmail.com)(?!yahoo.com)(?!hotmail.com)(?!yahoo.co.in)(?!aol.com)(?!abc.com)(?!xyz.com)(?!pqr.com)(?!rediffmail.com)(?!live.com)(?!outlook.com)(?!me.com)(?!msn.com)(?!ymail.com)([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
if (reg.test(email)){
return 0;
}
else{
alert('Please Enter Business Email Address');
return false;
}
});
```